# Cycles Normal Map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normal-map

I've been attempting normal mapping with three models now, and finally a normal map has worked in general, but when I try to apply it, it only produces a slightly-more shaded low-poly mesh.

Low-Poly
https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KcbG.png

High Poly https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MQxD.png

The nodes are there as well as the UV-normal map. I'm so confused and I haven't been able to find any other person with the same problem.